# macos terminal error messages when opening

Tags: macos, terminal

When I open the terminal, I get this error message.

```
Last login: Thu Jan 12 19:57:38 on ttys000
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:1: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew 
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:2: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:3: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:4: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:5: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:6: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/pratyush/.zprofile:7: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
pratyush@Pratyushs-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the M1 Mac and it was installed in /opt/homebrew/...

I opened /Users/~username~/.zprofile and it had three lines.
When you see them, all of the things named:

`eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)`

Put a hashtag sign in front of each one,

therefore `# eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)` e.g.

- Then when you do this, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> (do not press tab).
- You will see a folder called `zfiles` or `zprofile` (or something like this), so then press enter. This will save and solve your problem.

If you still are facing issues, type `nano .zprofile` in the terminal, and it should pop up. If you missed a hashtag put it in on like I said before. I think you saved the directory as part of the $ PATH folder and rooted it on your home-brew shell. Let me know if this works on your Mac.

(I just made this account on here since I too hated seeing this problem)